# Django Weasyprint: Timeout error loading css while site is hosted on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere, weasyprint

I'm struggling to use Django WeasyPrint correctly while exporting a template to PDF.

This issue only occurs on the PythonAnywhere version, using the view on `localhost` works as intended. Using any other view with the same stylesheets on PythonAnywhere also works fine.

The errors occur when loading these two resources:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/boostrap4.5.2.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
```

<sup>(note: I originally used a cdn for the bootstrap css but was finding a 403 forbidden error when WeasyPrint tried to get it instead, gave up on that one)</sup>
Here's the error log when weasyprint tries to use it:

```
Failed to load stylesheet at http://kirkmania.pythonanywhere.com/static/css/boostrap4.5.2.css : timeout: timed out
Failed to load stylesheet at http://kirkmania.pythonanywhere.com/static/css/blog.css : timeout: timed out
```

And here's the server log:

```
SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /cv/export (ip 10.0.0.52) !!!
uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 306] during GET /cv/export (10.0.0.52)
SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /static/css/boostrap4.5.2.css (ip 10.0.0.52) !!!
uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 248] during GET /static/css/boostrap4.5.2.css (10.0.0.52)
SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /static/css/blog.css (ip 10.0.0.52) !!!
uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 248] during GET /static/css/blog.css (10.0.0.52)
```

I haven't interacted with the wsgi stuff, honestly have no idea what's going with all that. I think it's hitting the 10 second timeout on the Weasyprint `url_fetcher`, which it shouldn't be.

Here's my weasyprint view code:

```
class ExportPDF(WeasyTemplateView):
    template_name='online_cv/export.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExportPDF, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        self.educations = cvEducation.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-start_date')
        self.jobs = cvWorkHistory.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-start_date')
        ...

        context['educations'] = self.educations
        context['jobs'] = self.jobs
        ...        

        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure weasyprint to use the PythonAnywhere proxy. Check the documentation for the libraries that you're using to see how to do that. The details you need to use are [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError/)